# How can i disable class in Razor page (.cshtml) angular 2 final

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, angular

```
<div class="spinner">
<div class="bounce1"></div>
<div class="bounce2"></div>
<div class="bounce3"></div>
</div>
```

How can i disable class spinner (css class) in Razor page?

I import in another page (index.cshtml)

`<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/mixin/spinner.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

and _Layout.cshtml

`@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)`

but class spinner it's show in Login.cshtml without import.
How can i disable in component or razor page ?

Comment: i can't use jquery in my project angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular2 you would do it like this:

```
<div [class.spinner]="yourCondition == true">
```

If the condition is true, that class ('spinner' in this case) will be added.
Otherwise it will be removed..